# Is it possible to open a download ebook file via iBook from titanium studio iPhone?

Tags: titanium, epub, titanium-modules

I would like to open ePub file in iBook application from Titanium application, trying to open ePub using **Titanium.UI.iOS.DocumentViewer**, but it’s not working.

Let me know if you have any suggestion or plugin which can allow to open ePub file from Titanium application.

Thanks
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Ti.Platform.openURL("ibooks://path-to-file");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i already tried that but its just opening iBook application, i would like to open my Book